# ODE Substitution Problem

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, initial-value-problems

Have some practice exam questions and answers to work through, I'm almost there but get stuck.

what we have is:

> $$
> \begin{cases}
> \dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{x^{3}-xt^{2}}{t^{3}}  \\ 
> x(1)=2 \\
> \end{cases}
> $$

and the (general solution) answer is:

$x(t) = \pm t\sqrt{\frac{2}{1-Dt^{4}}}$

now I figured that this is a substitution problem, using $y=\frac{x}{t}$ so that

$\frac{dx}{dt}=y^{3}-y$

and

$\frac{dy}{dt}=y+t\frac{dy}{dy}$

giving:

$y^{3}-2y = t\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\int{\frac{1}{y^3-2y}dy}=\int{\frac{1}{t}dt}$

$\ln{y^{3}-2y}=\ln{t}+C$

$y^{3}-2y=Dt$

and therefore:
$\frac{x^{3}}{t^{3}}-2\frac{x}{t}=Dt$

$x^3-2xt^{2}=Dt^{4}$

>

Here is where I get stuck... so I reverse engineered the solution to find that:

$x^{3}-2xt^{2}=x^{3}Dt^{4}$

and am now completely lost... where did that extra $x^{3}$ on the RHS of the equation come from??

Comment: How did you go from that integral with $y^3-2y$ in the denominator to $lny^3-2y$? That can't be right?

Comment: You could treat this as Bernoulli equation, using $u=x^{-2}$,...

Comment: I went from:

$y^{3}-2y=t\frac{dy}{dt}$

$\frac{1}{y^{3}-2y}=\frac{1}{t}\frac{dt}{dy}$

$\frac{1}{y^{3}-2y}dy=\frac{1}{t}dt$ and then integrated it

is this acceptable?? if no, whats the correct way?

Comment: ahhh crap... I never bothered to learn Bernoulli equations, although it was in the text book... thanks heaps LutzL!

Comment: $\int{\frac{1}{y^3-2y}dy}$ can be done with partial fraction decomposition

Comment: @imranfat

you mean:

$\frac{1}{y^{3}-2y}=\frac{A}{y^{3}}+\frac{B}{2y}$?????

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriou No, that is not partial fraction decomposition. But I would assume you'd seen partial fraction decomposition before before embarking on a differential equations course.

Comment: @imranfat

my bad... it would be $\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y^2}+\frac{C}{y^3}+\frac{D}{2y}$ or something?

Comment: @GeorgeDimitriou. See my post, can you work out details?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $\frac{dy}{y^3-2y}=\frac{dt}{t}$ is done alright. The anti derivative of $\frac{1}{t}dt$ is indeed $ln|t|$, however the anti derivative of $\frac{dy}{y^3-2y}$ cannot be $ln|y^3-2y|$ for the very simple reason, the derivative of $ln|y^3-2y|$ is not $\frac{1}{y^3-2y}$, in fact it is $\frac{3y^2-2}{y^3-2y}$ by Chain Rule!. So how to do $\int\frac{dy}{y^3-2y}$? The generic answer is using partial fraction decomposition (although this one could be done in a different way as well, see end of post).
So setting up the fractions (through factoring): $\frac{1}{y^3-2y}=\frac{A}{y}+\frac{B}{y-\sqrt{2}}+\frac{C}{y+\sqrt{2}}$. Multiply through by $y^3-2y$ and equating each equation with corresponding coefficients (which is 0,0,1 respectively from the numerator) gives $A+B+C=0,B\sqrt{2}-C\sqrt{2}=0,-2A=1$ results in $A=-0.5,B=1/4,C=1/4$ and you can now integrate $\int\frac{-0.5}{y}$+$\int\frac{0.25}{y-\sqrt{2}}$+$\int\frac{0.25}{y+\sqrt{2}}$$dy$. And done.   Now in THIS (I repeat THIS!) particular case, you could have subbed in $\int\frac{dy}{y^3-2y}$the substitution  $y=\frac{1}{v}$ and your integral would have become $\int\frac{-vdv}{1-2v^2}$ (verify!) which straight away would have become an $ln$ term. I will now leave it up to you to work out the rudiments. Good luck!